# Using background image as a link

Tags: html, css

Trying to use a html and css trick to give the impression of using a background image as a clickable link following this tutorial. I can't get to work, however, due to two issues:

1. The link is not filling the space of the background image
2. The link will not move off the screen
3. The card will move elsewhere, it will not go to where i would like to put(from the code i put in .card)
4. The h5 will not stay in the .card background image

I'm a beginner to html and CSS

```
<div class="card card1">
                <a href="#"><h5>Cakes</h5></a>
</div>



.card{
    width: 200px;
    height: 230px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 10px 15px;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}
.card1{
    background-image: url(file:///C:/Users/ACER/Desktop/Easy-Bake/cakewallpaper.jpg);

}
.card:hover{
    transform: translateY(-10px);
}
h5{
     text-shadow: 0 0 5px #999;
     font-size: 20px;

}
```

Comment: can u post the code somewhere publicly?

Comment: Reverse the wrapping function. Wrap the div inside the anchor element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap the div in the anchor tag

```
<a href="#">
   <div class="card card1">
       <h5>Cakes</h5>
   </div>
</a>
```